# Modeling binary outcome based on population characteristics

Tags: multiple-regression

I have two sets of population estimates, one of whom is eligible for a program and one who is not. I don’t have specific observations from these populations, just estimates of population characteristics. For example, in the eligible=0 population, I have the proportion belonging to several age groups, proportion belonging to four different race categories, and proportion metro/non-metro, all adding up to 1.

To help target outreach, I’d like to model eligibility based on actual value of those characteristics. For each real observation, we will have race, age and metro/non-metro. Ideally I could get probability of eligibility based on those characteristics, but other outputs are acceptable as well.

Is this possible? Any advice on where to start?